# erro quando seleciono imagem da galeria do android no meu app de fazer anotações

Tags: java, android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Galera é o seguinte, eu tenho um aplicativo de notas de diário bem simples na qual possui uma opção de selecionar e anexar uma foto na nota, a foto pode ser tirada na mesma hora com a camera ou importada da galeria, o problema é que quando vou importar da galeria, só da certo quando importo através da opção "galeria" que exibe todas as fotos, mas como vcs sabem, no menu esquerdo da galeria tem opções tipo "downloads", "imagens recentes" e se eu selecionar alguma imagem através dessas opções da erro , o app nao chega a fechar mas simplesmente nao consigo selecionar a imagem, só funciona se eu selecionar especificamente através da opção "galeria" . Segue abaixo o log de erro que da no aplicativo e as classes correspondentes ao erro:

```
public class Rounder {

    public static Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage, int width, int height) {
        int targetWidth = width;
        int targetHeight = height;
        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);

        Path path = new Path();

        float padding = 5;

        RectF rectF = new RectF( padding, padding, targetWidth-padding, targetHeight-padding);

        path.addRoundRect(rectF, (float)0.0*width, (float)0.0*width, Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(padding+10);

        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                sourceBitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth-10,
                        targetHeight-10), paint);

        //canvas.drawCircle(targetWidth/2, targetHeight/2,targetHeight/2, paint);


        return targetBitmap;
    }

}



public class NewDiaryFragment extends Fragment {

    Button addPhotoButton, addAudioButton,playPauseButton,restartPlayButton,deleteAudioButton,deletePhotoButton,
        addDiaryButton, cancelButton, datePickerButton;
    ImageView imageView;
    EditText textEditText;

    OneDiary oneDiary;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String audioPath,photoPath;
    Date date;
    Uri mImageCaptureUri;

    static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 2;

    AudioRecorder audioRecorder;
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer;

    Boolean isPlaying, isRecording;
    DiaryDB diaryDB;

    DateFormat[] df = new DateFormat[] {
            DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.US),
            DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(),
            DateFormat.getTimeInstance(),
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_diary, null);
        addAudioButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.record_audio_button);
        addPhotoButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.take_photo_button);
        deleteAudioButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_audio_button);
        deletePhotoButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_photo_taking_button);
        addDiaryButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_diary_button);
        cancelButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_new_diary_button);
        imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.photo_image_view);
        playPauseButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_button);
        restartPlayButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.restart_button);

        textEditText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.text_edit_text);
        datePickerButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);

        photoPath = "";

        date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerButton.setText(df[0].format(date));

        oneDiary = new OneDiary();
        diaryDB = new DiaryDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),GetRandomPic.getRandomPic());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(Rounder.getRoundedShape(bitmap, 300, 300));

        final String [] items = new String [] {getActivity().getString(R.string.select_image_dialog_camera), getActivity().getString(R.string.select_image_dialog_SD)};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.select_image_dialog_title));
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        addPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        audioPath = null;

        isPlaying = false;

        playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                audioRecorder.stopRecording();
                isRecording = false;
                addAudioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_icon);
                if (isPlaying) {
                    audioPlayer.pause();
                    playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
                    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                } else
                {
                    try {
                        audioPlayer.resume(audioPath);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(audioPath!=null) {
                        playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_play_icon);
                        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                    }
                }

            }
            });

        restartPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                audioRecorder.stopRecording();
                isRecording = false;
                addAudioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_icon);
                if(audioPath!=null){
                    try {
                        audioPlayer.play(audioPath);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_play_icon);
                    isPlaying = true;
                }
            }
        });

        isRecording = false;



        addAudioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if ( isRecording ){
                    audioRecorder.stopRecording();
                    addAudioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_icon);
                } else{
                    audioPlayer.stop();
                    isPlaying = false;
                    playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);

                    try {
                        audioPath = audioRecorder.startRecording(oneDiary.getId().toString()+".mp4");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("recorder","failed");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    addAudioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_record_icon);
                }
                isRecording = !isRecording;
            }
        });

        deleteAudioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                audioRecorder.stopRecording();
                audioPlayer.stop();
                if( audioPath!=null){
                    audioRecorder.deleteAudio();
                    audioPath = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Audio deletado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        deletePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if( !(bitmap==null) ){
                    bitmap = null;
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ha_ha);
                }
            }
        });

        addDiaryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    saveNewDiary();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                returnToMainActivity();
            }
        });

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if( !(audioPath==null)){
                    audioRecorder.deleteAudio();
                }
                returnToMainActivity();
            }
        });



        datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                DialogFragment fragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(new Date());
                fragment.setTargetFragment(NewDiaryFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
                fragment.show(fm,null);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public void saveNewDiary() throws IOException {
        oneDiary.setAudioPath(audioPath);
        savePhoto();
        oneDiary.setText(textEditText.getText().toString());
        oneDiary.setDate(date);
        diaryDB.addDiary(oneDiary);
    }

    public void savePhoto() throws IOException {
        if(bitmap!=null){
            photoPath = oneDiary.getId().toString();
            FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(photoPath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            photoPath = getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + photoPath;
            oneDiary.setPhotoPath(photoPath);
            //fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    }

    public void returnToMainActivity(){
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),DiaryList.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == MyActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(Rounder.getRoundedShape(bitmap, 300, 300));
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE & resultCode == MyActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            date = (Date) data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.Extra_Date);
            datePickerButton.setText(df[0].format(date));
        }
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE & resultCode == MyActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            String path;
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData(); //from Gallery
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = null;
            cursor  = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    mImageCaptureUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(Rounder.getRoundedShape(bitmap, 300, 300));
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        diaryDB.close();
        audioPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
    12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d89b20)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina, PID: 6934
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:73 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina.NewDiary}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina.Rounder.getRoundedShape(Rounder.java:41)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina.NewDiaryFragment.onActivityResult(NewDiaryFragment.java:311)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:165)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
12-01 15:24:58.455 6934-6934/com.here.superaitaotaotv.splentemedina E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[IMAGEM COM AS OPÇOES DA GALERIA QUE MENCIONEI ACIMA](http://i1195.photobucket.com/albums/aa385/splente/efefefeffefe.jpg)

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Clique em [edit] e adicione a imagem diretamente no site, esse link nem quis abrir aqui. Adicione tambem a classe que faz essa captura no seu aplicativo.

Comment: editado amigo  ;.

Comment: Não fecha mas dá erro? Que erro dá?

Comment: diz que o app parou : " o meu diario parou" no entanto so da erro pra puxar a imagem, o app continua aberto

Comment: Tem de rever a forma como obtém o *bitmap*. O erro diz que ele é nulo quando o passa ao método `getRoundedShape()`